# Powershell: Not working? $list = $list | Where-Object Name -NotContains $myPSCustomObject

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

I'm trying to use the output of [Get-LoggedOnUser.ps1](https://github.com/jaapbrasser/SharedScripts/blob/master/Get-LoggedOnUser/Get-LoggedOnUser.ps1) (which outputs a PSCustomObject) to filter a list of usernames.

Goal: I want to remove from my list any currently logged on users.
However, I cannot figure what I'm doing isn't working, even debugging in the ISE. You can see I've even tried to make the object's field names match eachother.

```
$currentlyLoggedInUsernames = .\Get-LoggedOnUser.ps1
$currentlyLoggedInUsernames = .\Get-LoggedOnUser.ps1 | Select-Object UserName, LogonTime | sort UserName, LogonTime
$currentlyLoggedInUsers = $currentlyLoggedInUsernames | Select-Object UserName | Select-Object @{Name = "Name"; Expression = {$_.UserName}}

$useraccounts = Get-ChildItem -path \\$env:COMPUTERNAME\c$\users\ -Exclude 'public', 'Administrator' | Where-Object Name -notcontains $env:USERNAME 
### Trouble below ###
$useraccounts = $useraccounts | Where-Object Name -NotContains $currentlyLoggedInUsers #BUT OTHER CURRENTLY LOGGED IN USERS REMAIN AFTER THIS LINE IS RUN.
$useraccounts #Why doesn't the above line actually remove the other logged in users from the list?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-notcontains` is to be used when you want to check a collection against a value. In your case, you are checking a value against a collection (the opposite). You need to use `-notin`é

**Example**

```
# To check if a value is in a collection
"A" -in @('A','B','C')

# To check if a collection contains a value.
@('A','B','C') -contains 'A'
```

Here is your sample code, simplified and revised.

```
$currentlyLoggedInUsers = .\Get-LoggedOnUser.ps1
$useraccounts = Get-ChildItem -path \\$env:COMPUTERNAME\c$\users\ -Exclude 'public', 'Administrator' | Where-Object Name -notcontains $env:USERNAME 

$NotLoggedInUsers = $useraccounts | Where-Object Name -notin $currentlyLoggedInUsers.Username
```

**References**

[About_Comparison_Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-5.1)